# How do I do multiple processes for Django, on my WSGI apache?

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, unix

My friend says that Django only has 1 thread or something?

And I have to edit my 000-default in order to add more processes? He suggests 4 or 5.

What exactly is this, and what do I have to do?

Thanks, I'm a noob.

Comment: "Django only has 1 thread or something"  Could you get an exact quote or link, please?  Your friend might be wrong.  Without details it's hard to know what your friends claim really is.  Do you have an actual performance problem?  Are things too slow?  Why are you asking?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`WSGIDaemonProcess`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) directive to put the app in daemon mode and specify the number of daemon processes and threads.

Comment: Read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading' to understand more about process/threading model. Also see example for daemon mode at end of 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide'.